# How to make a simple Django URLconf and reverse() on it for a test? (getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list')

Tags: django, python-2.7, integration-testing, django-urls

I am writing convenience code which calls [`django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) to generate links. However, I can't seem to write a simple [URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example) for a quick test.

This is what  I tried:

```py
>>> from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
>>> conf = patterns('', url(r'^foo/$', lambda request: None, name='foo'))
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('foo', conf)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File ".../env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 445, in reverse
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)
File ".../env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 27, in wrapper
    if mem_args in cache:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I'm using Django 1.5 on Python 2.7.

Comment: Try just with `reverse('foo')`. Why passing url `conf` in it?

Comment: Because I don't want to search the project-wide URLconf. I'm using an isolated URLconf for the test. `reverse('foo')` fails because there's no URL named "foo" in my project.

Comment: `patterns` returns a list. You might want to loop throught it, or do `conf[0]`

Comment: @karthikr that just gives an error about the RegEx pattern not containing patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider creating a `test_urls.py` module

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^foo/$', lambda request: None, name='foo'))
```

then give the path to `test_urls.py` when you call `reverse` in your test.

```
reverse('foo', 'path.to.test_urls')
```

If you really want to create the `urlconf` in your test, you need to make sure it has a `urlpatterns` attribute. The following works in Django 1.4.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class MockUrlConf(object):
    urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^foo/$', lambda request: None, name='foo'))

reverse('foo', MockUrlConf)
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't want to create a `test_urls.py` because it seemed like overkill for one URL. However the inner class solution works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`reverse` method's `urlconf` param is a string indicating the name of the module containing the `urls`. You may call it like this:

```
reverse('foo', 'your_app.urls' )
```

Now, I don't know how exactly change this behavior, you may create some `urls.py` for testing and calling them, but this seems hardly tight to the URL modules names in your `settings.py`.

The documentation isn-t very useful, it says basically [**you won't need to set `urlconf` param**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse). So I would listen to it and try another way.

Good luck!

Comment: This seemed like the answer I was coming to from poking around in the documentation, but Alasdair's answer also works and has the extra bonus that I don't need to create a file just for the single test URL. But I agree that the documentation is not very helpful!

Comment: I concur, Alasdair's answer was very nice.